# NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken ToastConfig! in jasmine spec for Angular + Electron project

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

**The problem**

Hi everybody! First time asking question here, hoping for some help. I'm currently developing a Electron+Angular application and I'm finally preparing for testing all the services and components. In trying to launch samples specs created with WebStorm along with components and services I'm facing the current error:

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[InjectionToken ToastConfig]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken ToastConfig]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken ToastConfig!
```

This is the simple test file I'm trying to run

```
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {CognitoService} from './cognito.service';
import {ToastrModule, ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';

describe('CognitoService', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ToastrModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [
        CognitoService,
        {provide: ToastrService, useClass: ToastrService}
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: CognitoService = TestBed.get(CognitoService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

This is the stacktrace I've obtained from running the test

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[InjectionToken ToastConfig]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken ToastConfig]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken ToastConfig!
    error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ InjectionToken ToastConfig ] })
        at <Jasmine>
        at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:724:1)
        at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:2093:1)
        at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:2037:1)
        at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:1941:1)
        at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:2093:1)
        at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:2037:1)
        at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:1941:1)
        at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20895:1)
        at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:21584:1)
        at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:627:1)
```

This is the current app module I have in the solution, as I've seen that it may depends on importing correctly ToastrModule here

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ModalModule, TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ConfirmationDialogComponent } from './shared/confirmation-dialog/confirmation-dialog.component';
import {SharedModule} from './shared/shared.module';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedModule,
    LayoutModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width'
    }),
    TooltipModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
  ],
  entryComponents: [ConfirmationDialogComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**What I've tried**

- Verified that `ToastrModule.forRoot`is in the import section
- Removed / Added "jasmine", "jest" in tsconfig.spec.json which is an extension of

  tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

- Tried npm update
- Tried to install @types/jasmine and @types/jest

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

PS: if you need further information, I'll try to add them as soon as possible

Answer (score 30):

Try to specify the position of toaster otherwise it will give null Inject error

app.module.ts

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      positionClass :'toast-bottom-right'
    })
  ],
```

Answer (score 16):

```
const toastrService = {
  success: (
    message?: string,
    title?: string,
    override?: Partial<IndividualConfig>
  ) => {},
  error: (
    message?: string,
    title?: string,
    override?: Partial<IndividualConfig>
  ) => {},
};
```

Use the stub inside provider array

```
{ provide: ToastrService, useValue: toastrService }
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `MockService(ToastrService)` to create a full mock automatically.

Answer (score 6):

Adding ToastrModule.forRoot() to my.component.spec.ts works for me

```
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
    imports: [
      IonicModule.forRoot(),
      ToastrModule.forRoot() // added this works for me
    ], ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't replicate but using `ToastrModule.forRoot()` works for me .

But I did it stubbing my custom service wrapped around Toastr and used it like this .

```js
 providers: [
    { provide : ToasterNotificationService,
      useClass : ToasterStub
    }
  ]
```

ToasterStub class  is :

```js
class ToasterStub {
 showSuccess(message: string, title: string): void {}
 showError(message: string, title: string): void {}
 showInfo(message: string, title: string): void {}
 showWarning(message: string, title: string): void {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error shows due to Toastr version compatibility issues with the Angular version. I also got the same kind of error and it solved after when i changed it to Toastr version to `"^10.0.4"`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I was testing library linked with other library and I have forgotten to add `"preserveSymlinks": true,` into `angular.json` and `tsconfig.lib.json`.